# Scroll Down on a div/popup using iMacros?

Tags: scroll, imacros

I am not able to scroll down using iMacros on the followers page on an Instagram user. The code below scrolls down the whole window, but not the popup that is under the code.

URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,20000)

I think that it is relevant to the div with the class _4gt3b, but I am not an expert and need help.

[the div i am trying to scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSxp5.png)

And here is the link of the page:

https://www.instagram.com/sfktl/followers/

I have searched for this issue a lot and was not able to find any solution. Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the div class is correct then the `EVENT` command must work:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="div._4gt3b" KEY=35
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. I also found this to be working by the way: EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)" KEY=40 MODIFIERS="meta"